# Errors using WAMP for local hosting site and Dreamweaver to edit theme

Tags: localhost, fatal-error, offline

I would like to make offline edits the theme of my live wordpress site using Dreamweaver.

Setup:

Running Windows 10 64-bit and Wamp 64-bit and have exported my database from the live site to the localhost through phpadmin. I'm making sure that the wp-config file has the correct database info and that I'm using incognito mode in Chrome to avoid any cache related issues.

Errors when plugins are enabled through database:

> Fatal error: Class 'SiteOrigin_Panels_Revisions' not found in
>   C:\wamp64\www\catalog\wp-content\plugins\siteorigin-panels\siteorigin-panels.php

Errors when plugins are disabled through database:

`localhost/catalog/wp-admin` redirects me to the live site login when expecting it to take me to `localhost` path login
`localhost/catalog/wp-admin.php/` redirects me to my main page

Dreamweaver errors: "Dynamically-related files could not be resolved because the site definition is not correct for this server." I am getting this error even with permalinks set to plain and when I have my testing server setup according my wamp folder path as `localhost/catalog` and server model selected as PHP MySQL.

I just want to be able to host locally with plugins active and be able to edit the html of the index of my main page `localhost/catalog-` but it is a php file, so I went to Live Code View in Dreamweaver, copied and pasted that html code that shows up in Live Code View, and pasted it in an html file, but then this html makes the site look all messed up.

Any help for any of these problems would greatly be appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Dreamweaver, make sure that the Site settings for the remote site are set properly to your local folder.

(Plus the standard "Don't make code changes to a theme, as a theme update will overwrite your changes. Use a Child Theme.")

Comment: Okay, thanks for the response. The Dreamweaver Site settings are already set properly. I will use a child theme, but I would also like the ability to edit this main theme too, and identify the causes of the current problems.

Comment: Off-topic-your-question, but a child theme allows you to make changes to theme code. Just copy the theme code file you want to modify into your child theme folder, and make changes in the file in the child theme folder. Read up on how child themes work. As for your DW problem; dunno....I set up a development site on my hosting place, then transfer files to the live place, so I don't have to worry about things being different in my local machine vs live site.

Comment: Okay, themes aside, I want to modify the html of index.php in localhost/catalog- but it is a php file. How would I modify it without messing around in the themes folders and child themes? Thanks.

Comment: Getting a bit off-topic here, which will irritate some 'responders', but you'll need to understand the template hierarchy of WordPress. Start here https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/ . Then look at how Child Themes work: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/advanced-topics/child-themes/ . (That topics list on the left side of both of those pages will help; you may want to start at the beginning of the whole thing.)